# Библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI, не работает parse_mode

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Такой вопрос: при использования метода `parse_mode = 'html'` выдает ошибку? в чем может быть проблема?

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
    def main_start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<h1>Информация: ... ... ...</h1>', parse_mode='html')
```

Ошибка:

```
raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unsupported start tag "h1" at byte offset 0
```

Comment: Тег h1 не поддерживается в Telegram Bot API, загугли поддерживаемые теги